# Error al ejecutar aplicaciones web desarrolladas en NetBeans (Browser refused to debug this tab)

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp

Cordial saludo equipo agradezco su colaboración con el siguiente inconveniente, estoy desarrollado un aplicativo web haciendo uso del lenguaje de programación Java Web (JSP) en el editor Apache NetBeans IDE versión  21

Al momento de correr la aplicación web me muestra el siguiente error, en una ventana:
Browser refused to debug this tab.
Close Chrome Developer Tools (or any other browser debugger) and try again.

En el explorador me aparece el siguiente error:
Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Investigando  y verificando en youtube ellos arreglan el inconveniente a sea ejecutando otro explorador  o averiguando en ChatGPT, hacen énfasis en problemas de conexión de red, pero en este punto vale la pena aclarar que estoy trabajando en una conexión sencilla entre el lenguaje de programación JSP/Java  en el editor NetBeans con una base de datos MySQL (PHPMyadmin): Con la siguientes configuraciones:
Librerias:
•   Mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar
•   JDK 1.8
•   GlassFish server con las siguientes características:
GlassFish Server 5.1.0 on http//localhost:4848

Y la base de datos MySQL(PHPMyAdmin), tiene la siguientes características:
Se esta ejecutando con el motor local XAMPP v3.3.0
Puerto 8081
Agradezco la colaboración que me puedan brindar, no se por que se presenta este inconveniente.

Saludos!.

Comment: El verdadero error es _Communications link failure: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago_. ¿Está corriendo realmente el servicio de MySQL? ¿Estás usando la propiedades de conexión correctas? Recuerda mostrar un [repro].

Comment: Cordial saludo muchas gracias por la colaboración, en el siguiente video explico ms a profundidad el inconveniente que se me presenta: https://youtu.be/qtq2gmFImz4

Comment: Recuerda siempre proporcionar un [repro] _en la pregunta misma_, por dos motivos: 1. los enlaces pueden caer más adelante, 2. para proveer más contexto a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, el problema es que no puedes tener la clave en blanco, cuando instalaste el mysql debio pedirte una clave para root, esa es la que debes usar